# drawing arc between two annotations on MKMapView in iphone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

i want to draw an arc between two annotations on a MKMapView. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using `MKPolyline`. At First you need to get coordinates of arc, then draw polylines over it. You will find an example [here](http://navarra.ca/?p=786) to draw polyline over some coordinates.